# I want to display a field from my current table and a field from other table but I got error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have three tables: appointment, prescription and medication.

Appointment table have relationship with prescription and prescription have relationship with medication.

I already can get the field which is medicationType on medication table and display on the datagridview. From appointment table, jump to prescription and then jump to medication to grab the medicationType field.

But now I want to display one more field which is aStatus from appointment table, how to do it?

I got this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Help.

[image: I want to display aStatus from appointment table too]

MY TABLE
[image: my table]

> > Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
> >     Incorrect syntax near 'ap'.

```
private void LoadPrescriptionRecords()
{    
    //retrieve connection information info from App.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //STEP 1: Create connection
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    //STEP 2: Create command
    /*
    string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, app.aDate, med.medicationName, pat.pFirstname, pay.amount FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN medication as med on pres.medicationid = med.medicationid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment as app on pres.appointmentid = app.appointmentid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN patient as pat on pres.patienpaymentidtid = pat.patientid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN payment as pay on pres. = pay.paymentid";
    */
    /*
    string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID FROM APPOINTMENT";
    SqlCommand cmdAPPOINTMENT = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    string strCommandText2 = "SELECT medicationID FROM PRESCRIPTION WHERE appointmentID IN (" + strCommandText + ")";
    SqlCommand cmdPRESCRIPTION = new SqlCommand(strCommandText2, myConnect);
    */

    string strCommandText3 = "SELECT m.medicationType, ap.appointmentID,ap.aStatus MEDICATION m, (SELECT p.medicationID, a.appointmentID,a.aStatus from APPOINTMENT a, PRESCRIPTION p WHERE a.appointmentID = p.appointmentID) ap WHERE aa.medicationID = aa.medicationID";
    //string strCommandText3 = "SELECT nFirstName FROM NURSE WHERE nurseID= (" + strCommandText2 + ")";

    myConnect.Open();

    /*
    SqlDataReader readAPPOINTMENT = cmdAPPOINTMENT.ExecuteReader();
    readAPPOINTMENT.Close();

    SqlDataReader readPRESCRIPTION = cmdPRESCRIPTION.ExecuteReader();
    readPRESCRIPTION.Close();

    SqlDataReader readMEDICATION = cmdMEDICATION.ExecuteReader();
    */ 

    PrescriptionAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText3, myConnect);

    //readMEDICATION.Close();
    myConnect.Close();      

    //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
    // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PrescriptionAdapter);
    // Empty Employee Table first
    Prescription.Clear();
    // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
    // using SELECT statement
    PrescriptionAdapter.Fill(Prescription);

    // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
    if (Prescription.Rows.Count > 0)
        grdPrescription.DataSource = Prescription;         
}
```

Comment: And **please** start using **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection attacks! See: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: Its ok, it's a school project. I want to ask what method am i using to display other field from other table? I know there is inner join, outer join, but what is my method called?  @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute single query to get fields from multiple fields. Please check following code. Note that this query is not tested may be you need some changes.

```
    string strCommandText3 = "SELECT m.medicationType,ap.appointmentID,ap.aStatus FROM MEDICATION as m, (SELECT p.medicationID, a.appointmentID,a.aStatus from
APPOINTMENT a, PRESCRIPTION p WHERE a.appointmentID = p.appointmentID) ap WHERE m.medicationID = ap.medicationID ";
```

Comment: Ok i changed to your codes, no error this time. But aStatus still doesn;t come out, only medicationType come out only. See my above codes @Sameer

Comment: I changed my answer please check.

Comment: Looks confusing. Do i need to delete the strCommandText and strCommandText2 line. Only use this line right which is your strCommandText3. @Sameer

Comment: See my code above,  I got error. Incorrect syntax near 'm'. Incorrect syntax near 'ap'. Added a image too @Sameer

Comment: I changed query check now.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Modify your query so that a set of values is allowed. Example: Use `IN` instead of `=`

2) Modify your subquery so that it returns only one row. Example: Use `MAX()` function to reduce many rows to one.

Comment: I changed the = to IN. At WHERE appointmentID= to appointmentID IN, and WHERE medicationID= to medicationID IN and it worked. I want to ask what method am i using to display other field from other table? I know there is inner join, outer join, but what is my method called?  @Sameer

Comment: You are not using join it is simple where query. `JOIN` used for getting data from two different table using single query. like : `SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;`

Comment: I see thanks. Now I also want to display aStatus field from appointment table, but got error. Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. I alr edited my codes. How to do it? @Sameer